# Installing MySQL version 5.7 on ubuntu 20.04 machine

Tags: installation, dependencies, ubuntu-20.04, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

So I have tried to downgrade installed mysql version-8 to version-5.7 on ubuntu 20.04 machine. But couldnt do it. I have the below issues.

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
he following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-client : Depends: mysql-community-client (= 5.7.42-1ubuntu18.04)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I did save a signiture key in a file for mysql v-5.7 and added to apt repo

1. sudo apt-key add signature.key
2. sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic mysql-5.7" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list'
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
5. sudo apt install -f mysql-client=5.7* mysql-community-server=5.7* mysql-server=5.7*

but the result of step-5 is the mentioned problem.